# How do you get the Ore behind the glass in stage 'Fuel'?

Tags: prodeus

As asked above, I can't figure out how to get the Ore secret behind the glass in the stage 'Fuel'.  The automap is not helpful either as it doesn't show any way to get in there from another angle.

[image: The ore behind the glass]

[image: Automap of the location]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Go to the bottom of the nearby staircase, grab the automap, and look on the back of the pillar by the window for a hidden switch. Press it to retract the wall, then collect the goods.

[image: Hidden button to retract the glass]

This [site](https://gameranx.com/features/id/374112/article/prodeus-finding-all-the-secrets-and-ore-fragments-on-fuel/) shows how to find all the ores.

Comment: Honestly don't know how I missed that.  Thanks.